# Voltar para outra dialogAlert

Tags: java, android

Tenho um sistema de captura de processos no Android no qual quando detectado algo suspeito, o mesmo emite uma janela de alerta com algumas opções. Gostaria de saber como eu faço para quando eu abrir alguma dessas opções, ao pressionar o botão de voltar, que a aplicação exibisse a janela de aviso anterior.

Por exemplo, a janela de alerta principal

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Sistema Infectado. Aplicação capturada "+ameaca);
                 builder.setIcon(R.drawable.alert);
                showNotificationWarning(); // NOTIFICAÇÃO DE ALERTA
                builder.setItems(new CharSequence[]
                                {"Desinstalar aplicação", "Ignorar", "Detalhes", "Continuar Monitoramento",},
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                switch (which) {
                                final AlertDialog.Builder detalhes = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

                                        detalhes.setTitle("Detalhes");// outra janela de aviso. Gostaria que quando eu estivesse nessa janela, ao apertar o back button, voltasse para a primeira janela de aviso
                                        detalhes.setIcon(R.drawable.settings);
```

Comment: Em vez de um *AlertDialog* use uma *Activity*

Answer (score 0):

Cria uma chamada do primeiro AlertDialog dentro do método `onBackPressed()`

Comment: em qualquer lugar ?